# rand.randrange returning 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randrange'

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have the problem that rand.randrange won't work. From searching the internet I found that this is from a different file that is named random. If I do

```
print(random, type(random))
```

then I get the following result

> ```
> <built-in method random_sample of mtrand.RandomState object at 0x111f70b40> <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
> ```
>
> My imports are the following:
>   
>   `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>   import random as rand
>   from pylab import *`

I use a mac and python 3.7.1. Could somebody tell me what I need to do and how to fix this issue?

Sebastiaan

Comment: You've got something weird going on in your `import`.  Show those too.

Comment: @MarkRansom i have put my imports in the question.

Comment: Since you imported `random` as `rand` you're getting a different `random` from somewhere else, maybe `pylab`.  Never import `*` because you never know what you're getting.

Comment: @MarkRansom thank you for helping me, my project now works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python version 3.7 it should be `random.random()`. you can refer more details using this [link](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html). So your print statement should be `print(rand.random(), type(random))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your rand is random.random, so it don't have attribute 'randrange'

```
>>> from random import random as rand
>>> print(rand.randrange(10, 20))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randrange'
```

Should do it like this

```
>>> import random as rand
>>> print(rand.randrange(10, 20))
11
```